# Mater-master database replication on 5 servers

Tags: database, replication, cluster-computing

My current project requires immediate replication between 5 databases. Servers are physically distributed across the globe. Currently we use Redis with one master server installed on another 6th server. All database writes on any of 5 servers are performed to this 6th master server, and other 5 are slaves of it. This approach has a lot of flaws and i'm looking for solution to replace it. Any suggestions please?

Comment: This question is perhaps more suited to dba.stackexchange?